# What's an efficient way (without parsing and re-encoding) to put a string representing JSON into a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON string which has been generated by Jbuilder:

```
json = "{name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}"
```

This is currently a string. However I want to combine it into a new hash (ideally in Ruby) before finally outputting it as JSON.

i.e.

```
output = {result: :success, data: json}
```

However if I convert this to JSON the `json` value gets double-encoded such that it's sent as a string:

```
output.to_json
#=> "{\"result\":\"success\",\"data\":\"{name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}\"}"
```

Now I could parse the JSON into a Ruby hash and then re-output it but that seems like a big fat waste of parsing when what I'd really like to do is to say "hey, this node is already JSON, don't re-encode it already!".

Is there any equivalent to the `raw()` method Rails has in views? i.e.

```
output = {result: :success, data: raw(json)}
```

so that the json evaluation of this then becomes:

```
output.to_json
#=> "{\"result\":\"success\",\"data\": {\"name\":\"Peter\",\"email\":\"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}"
```

Comment: Given `raw` is an `ActionView` helper and therefore a rails feature mainly intended for template engines I doubt you will find a JSON encoder that respects it (given it just prevents HTML encoding). I have never seen an equivalent version for JSON and I could not find one.

Comment: You could use [Oj gem](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) - that suppose to be fastest Ruby JSON gem out there - and then do something like `render text: Oj.dump(my_object)`

Comment: Your `json` String is not a valid JSON string by the way; keys should be strings enclosed by double quotes, just like string values (single quotes are not valid).

Comment: Daniël Knippers is correct.  This would be the proper string to parse `JSON.parse '{"name": "Peter", "email": "peter@stackoverflow.com"}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a way you can do this, it’s a bit of a hack but you might find it useful.

First restating the problem:

```
# Note the quotes, your example isn't actually valid
json = "{\"name\": \"Peter\", \"email\": \"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}"

output = {result: :success, data: json}

# Without changing anything
puts JSON.generate(output)
```

This results in the following, where the value of `data` is a single string:

```
{"result":"success","data":"{\"name\": \"Peter\", \"email\": \"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}"}
```

The json gem uses a `to_json` method that is added to all objects to convert them to json, so the simplest fix would be to replace that method on objects you want to behave differently:

```
# As before
json = "{\"name\": \"Peter\", \"email\": \"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}"

# Replace to_json on the singleton object
def json.to_json *args
  self
end

output = {result: :success, data: json}

# Generate the output (output.to_json gives the same result)
puts JSON.generate(output)
```

This creates the following, where the `data` value is now itself a hash, as desired:

```
{"result":"success","data":{"name": "Peter", "email": "peter@stackoverflow.com"}}
```

A cleaner way to do this, to avoid manipulating singletons in your code could be to create a subclass of string that has this behaviour:

```
class JsonSafeString < String
  def to_json *args
    self
  end
end
```

You can now create a `JsonSafeString` when you want the contents included directly in a JSON object:

```
json = "{\"name\": \"Peter\", \"email\": \"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}"
output = {result: :success, data: JsonSafeString.new(json)}

puts JSON.generate(output)
```

The result is the same as above:

```
{"result":"success","data":{"name": "Peter", "email": "peter@stackoverflow.com"}}
```

You could wrap the call to `JsonSafeString.new` in a method like `raw_json` if you wanted.

Obviously this leaves the task of ensuring your string is valid to you – the main point of using a library for this is the user doesn’t have to concern themselves with things like whether to use single or double quotes, so you could be vulnerable to generating invalid JSON if you’re not careful. Also this is just a quick hack, there are probably a load of things I haven’t considered. In particular I haven’t taken character encodings into account, so watch out.

Comment: That's a really cool answer and gave me a way of thinking about it that I totally hadn't considered before. Both ways are interesting and the JsonSafeString object is a particularly nice approach

Comment: If the string is blank then you get invalid JSON. For example, `JSON.generate({ foo: JsonSafeString.new(nil.to_s) })` returns `{"foo":}`. You can update `to_json` to return `self.present? ? self : '""'` to ensure it returns valid JSON that can be consumed by `JSON.parse`. `.present?` requires ActiveSupport, so pure Ruby will need slightly different code.

Comment: As a follow up to my comment, our linter prefers `(presence || '""')` over the ternary `self.present? ? self : '""'`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't address your question, but may help you avoid it altogether...

Do you really need to generate your `json` variable into JSON before adding it to the hash? Jbuilder can generate a hash just as easily as a JSON string, e.g.:

```
hash = Jbuilder.new do |json|
  json.name 'Peter'
  json.email 'peter@stackoverflow.com'
end.attributes!
# => {"name"=>"Peter", "email"=>"peter@stackoverflow.com"}

output = {result: :success, data: hash}
```

Comment: That's a really good thought, thank you for suggesting it. It may actually be what I go with in the end. I'm going to mark @matt's answer as correct because he gave me the effect I actually asked for (a method that effectively delivered raw()) but this could well be what I ultimately use

Answer (score 0):

eval will put it out as raw code.

```
eval "{name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}"
=> {:name=>"Peter", :email=>"peter@stackoverflow.com"}
```

And the results.

```
output = {result: :success, data: eval("{name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}") }
=> {:result=>:success, :data=>{:name=>"Peter", :email=>"peter@stackoverflow.com"}}
```

And to string

```
output.to_s
=> "{:result=>:success, :data=>{:name=>\"Peter\", :email=>\"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}}"
```

And JSON

```
require 'json'
=> true 
output.to_json
=> "{\"result\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"email\":\"peter@stackoverflow.com\"}}"
```

Comment: Interesting answer. It definitely achieves the goal I'm after but I have a feeling that it actually does it accidentally. What you've done there is assume that the JSON is valid Ruby and parse it into a Ruby object. I don't know whether it's the case that eval'd JSON is also valid Ruby but I'd guess it's not. The formal way to do this would be to use `JSON.parse(string)` and then convert it back into JSON. However the unnecessary overhead of this is what I was trying to avoid ...

Comment: Ruby has an accepted standard for `{key: "value"}` being the same as `{:key=>"value"}` .  So that will parse fine.  I use the `key: 'value'` way to make my rails views look much nicer when setting options.

Comment: The biggest issue with eval though is you have to know you're not going to accidentally pass it malicious code.  You can always scope it by using a binding http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-metaprogramming.html#h4_1 ... but that still doesn't prevent any actionable code from being ran.  Still if you're only passing in value pairs within Hash brackets you should be fine.

Comment: For example `eval "{puts: 'hello world!'}"` returns a Hash with the key :puts and does not execute puts.  So what's within "{ }" should be okay to eval.

Comment: If the goal is to avoid parsing the string as JSON, I’m not sure parsing it as Ruby instead really achieves much. Also this depends on the string being valid Ruby – a valid JSON string won’t be e.g. `eval {"name": 'Peter', "email": 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}` will give a syntax error.

Comment: Right because you're not evaluating a string.  In both his and my example we start with the string `json = "{name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@stackoverflow.com'}"`